# Devise - confirmable undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I've recently acquired the Ruby code for a website my company is now developing. I've installed Rails, and run bundle to get the gems. I then set up PostgreSQL and changed the details in the database.yml file. I run `rake db:migrate` and it returns `undefined method confirmable' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Table:0xaeae3cc>`

Devise is installed, but if I run `rails g devise:install`, it tells me to do some manual setup, which I have ensured is done. 
The app is hosted on Heroku if that helps.

devise (2.1.2, 2.0.0)
rails (3.2.8, 3.2.0)

Comment: can you post your migration file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a devise resource for user using

```
rails generate devise user
```

Comment: I've done this, and there already is one. Do I need to delete the one that already exists, and redo it?

Comment: no the problem is somewhere else. post your database migration file on gist.github.com and post here

Comment: There's 50 of them, so I combined them. The link is [http://gist.github.com/3713388](http://gist.github.com/3713388)

Comment: in your AddDeviseToUsers migration trying uncommenting the lines below line 24 and run migrate

Answer (score 0):

If you have set up `confirmable` module after initial generation of Devise’s migration, you need to [create the migration by hand](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users):

```
class AddConfirmableToDevise < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :users, :confirmation_token, :string
    add_column :users, :confirmed_at, :datetime
    add_column :users, :confirmation_sent_at, :datetime
    # add_column :users, :unconfirmed_email, :string # Only if using reconfirmable
    add_index :users, :confirmation_token, unique: true
    execute("UPDATE users SET confirmed_at = NOW()")
    # All existing user accounts should be able to log in after this.
    # Remind: Rails using SQLite as default. And SQLite has no such function :NOW.
    # Use :date('now') instead of :NOW when using SQLite.
    # => execute("UPDATE users SET confirmed_at = date('now')")
    # Or => User.all.update_all confirmed_at: Time.now
  end

  def down
    remove_columns :users, :confirmation_token, :confirmed_at, :confirmation_sent_at
    # remove_columns :users, :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable
  end
end
```